# Digitally sign my word or pdf document with timestamp

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, digital-signature

I need to find a way to digitally sign my word or PDF document with a digital timestamp to prove that the content (mainly text content and images) has not been changed since ever then.

I need whoever access the document has a confident that the document is intact and original.

Is there any trustable online service that i can make use of? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on who you are trying to convince, you may get away with a self signed certificate, or you may need to go the extra mile.
The only way to provide absolute proof of authenticity is to follow the procedures od digital document signing, and in most jurisdictions it goes something like this:

1. Get a document signing digital certificate - you can most likely get it by finding certificate authority in your country and buying one or (in some countries) you may be able to get one for free if you have biometric ID - contact the authorities who gave you (or made you pay for) your ID. Digital certificate identifies you and replaces your handwritten signature, and it can be personal or business.
2. Get a timestamping server service from certificate authority in your country, as untrusted timestamping service may make your documents invalid and inadmissible in court, so anyone may dispute their validity - even outside of court. I suggest you get this service from local certificate authority because if you find yourself in a legal battle it's much easier to communicate with local provider. There may be some free timestamping options out there, but if they go belly-up you are screwed and your document authenticity may go out the window.
3. Setup your Adobe Reader / Microsoft Word by following the instructions from your certificate authority to the letter as they must make sure that this signing procedure complies with the law.

Note that some digital certificates may expose your personal data such as your name, address, some sort of personal ID number your country has, whatever it's called.
Also some countries may only permit use of Adobe PDF/A compliant documents and signing Word files may be as useful as smearing poo on paper document and calling it legally binding.
If the other party is not in your country, make sure to confirm that your signature is valid under their law (e.g. your country allows using Word docs, and the other one does not)

These are just basic guidelines to make your document (almost) bulletproof, so if you do not trust the other party, get on the phone with certificate authority, explain what you need to do and make sure you follow what they say.